# Download LibreOffice 4.1.3 EXACT version

Tags: libreoffice

I need to quickly download LibreOffice 4.1.3 or I'll lose out on something important. I've tried renaming the older installs that are close to that version number. I'm not seeing any archives (like Mozilla's FTP). There is a bug that is preventing me from opening, uninstalling *and* installing new versions.

This question could ALSO be answered if there is a universal uninstaller that is also put together by The Document Foundation.

Comment: Why not ask us about solving the actual problem you face instead of asking up to provide a download link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site seems to be a mirror for the LibreOffice project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libreoffice.mirror/

In the official archive for old versions of LibreOffice,

http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/

I unfortunately couldn't find your version but only versions 4.1.3.1 and 4.1.3.2.

The exact version you are looking for can be found on the first site, available for Windows, Linux and MacOS:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libreoffice.mirror/files/LibreOffice%204.1.3/

Comment: Hello!  While this may help, link-only answer are considered a no-no.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answers (like why would the user go here and grab this file? What is it? Why will it help?) and cite the site as a source.

Comment: Link-only answer is a yes-yes, up-voting to counter techie007's down-vote: thank you for making my day suck that much less.

Comment: @techie007: Edited, hope that's better

Comment: @neocrow Much better.  Have an upvote! :)